# URL not loading in WebView properly

Tags: java, javascript, android, browser, webview

I have a WebView that I want to point to a certain URL. For some reason the following code just opens the regular Android browser. I want it to load in my webview.

```
webView =  (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Can you post more code ? It's really strange that it opens the browser.

Comment: Do you have 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

in your manifest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this example and it worked:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html